# Unknown Provider: $scopeProvider When Testing Angular Controller With Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am trying to implement unit testing for a particular controller of a web app using Jasmine and Karma. At the moment it is giving the following error:

> ```
> Chrome 53.0.2785 (Mac OS X 10.10.5) HomeCtrl should be defined FAILED
>   Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$injector/unpr?p0=%24scopeProvider%20%3C-%20%24scope
> ```

Here is the code of the testing file:

```
describe('HomeCtrl', function(){
    var $controller, HomeCtrl;

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('TestModule'));

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, _$rootScope_, _$scope_) {
        $controller = _$controller_;
        rootScope = $rootScope.new();
        scope = $scope.new();
        HomeController = $controller('HomeCtrl', {
                $scope: scope
        });
    }));

    // Verify our controller exists
    it('should be defined', function() {
        expect(HomeController).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you seen this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27810179/angular-unit-test-unknown-provider-scopeprovider? Does it help? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I have seen it. I do not see how they are doing anything differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In AngularJS, all scopes are children of `$rootScope`.

In unit tests, you cannot *inject* `$scope` since, there is no service that exists. But there is an [$rootScope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope) provider which contains [API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) like `$new` to create a new child scope.

`$rootScope.$new()`, create a new child scope.

Since, you cannot *inject* `$scope` you are getting (no such provider exists to provide you `$scope`)

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope
```

In the answer, you have provided,

```
 beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, _$rootScope_) {
   $controller = _$controller_;
   $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
   HomeCtrl = $controller('HomeCtrl', {
    $scope: $rootScope,
   });
  }));
```

You are injecting `$rootScope` and directly passing the `$rootScope` to `HomeCtrl`. It works, but while executing tests it adds all variables and function in controller code to `$rootScope`.

But in real scenario, your `HomeCtrl` is expecting a `$scope`(child scope). So, to replicate the actual scenario, it would be better if you pass a child scope.

```
beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, _$rootScope_) {
  $controller = _$controller_;
  $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
  HomeCtrl = $controller('HomeCtrl', {
   $scope: $scope,
  });
 }));
```

Comment: Thanks. This was instructive and helpful!

Answer (score 1):

The following code succeeds:

```
describe('HomeCtrl', function(){
    var $controller, HomeCtrl;
    var $rootScope, $scope;

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('TestModule'));

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, _$rootScope_) {
        $controller = _$controller_;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        HomeCtrl = $controller('HomeCtrl', {
                $scope: $rootScope,
        });
    }));

    // Verify our controller exists
    it('should be defined', inject(function($controller) {
        expect(HomeCtrl).toBeDefined();
    }));
});
```