# Angular controller not injected in test

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I have a simple login controller:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('login', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {

    }])
    .controller('LoginCtrl', ["$scope", "$route", "LoginService", function ($scope, $route, LoginService) {
        var self = this;
        this.showGuestLogin = true;
        this.showUserLogin = false;

        this.toggleUserLoginType = function () {
            this.showGuestLogin = !this.showGuestLogin; 
            this.showUserLogin = !this.showUserLogin;
        }

        this.submitGuestLogin = function()
        {
            if(this.guestName === undefined || this.guestName.trim() == '')
            {
                self.loginError = "Name cannot be blank";
                return; 
            }

            LoginService.loginAsGuest(this.guestName.trim())
            .then(function()
            {
                self.loginError = null;
                $route.reload();
            })
            .catch(function(err)
            {
                self.loginError = 'An error occured. Please try again';
            });
        }
    }]);
```

I am trying to test it with:

```
describe('LoginCtrl', function()
{
    beforeEach(module('login'));

    var ctrl;

    beforeEach(inject(function($controller)
    {
        ctrl = $controller('LoginCtrl');
    }));

    it('should set error if guest name is undefined', function(done)
    {
        ctrl.guestName = undefined;
        ctrl.submitGuestLogin();
        expect(ctrl.loginError).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

But I am getting this error in console when test runs

> Error: [$injector:unpr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/unpr?p0=%24scopeProvider%20%3C-%20%24scope%20%3C-%20LoginCtrl

I can see in the developer console in the karma driven browser that the controller and it's dependant files are all being loaded correctly.

I can't see what is wrong?

**UPDATE**

I have tried the suggestions of passing an empty object:

```
beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $scope, $route, LoginService)
{
    ctrl = $controller('LoginCtrl', { 

    });
}));
```

and setting up the dependencies:

```
beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $scope, $route, LoginService)
{
    ctrl = $controller('LoginCtrl', { 
        $scope: $scope,
        $route: $route,
        LoginService: LoginService
    });
}));
```

Both of which give me this error:

> Error: [$injector:unpr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/unpr?p0=%24scopeProvider%20%3C-%20%24scope

Comment: Oh, I see I am not the only one with this odd problem...I haven't figured it out but seems to me something is wrong with the generator. Are you using a generator?

Comment: You mean a boilerplate code generator? If so, no, started from scratch. Got tests around my services that run fine too.

Comment: Probably you forgot a second parameter in this line `ctrl = $controller('LoginCtrl');`. You should add an object as the second parameter eg. `ctrl = $controller('LoginCtrl', { });`. This second mocks Controller's scope.

Comment: I added an empty object, different error.

Comment: It's still to broad. Could you please add some more information such as, which libs you are using. For more information, try to access this [link - Testing AngularJS](https://scotch.io/tutorials/testing-angularjs-with-jasmine-and-karma-part-2)

Answer (score 2):

It's because you need to add in the scope in the injection like this:

```
beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $scope) {
    ctrl = $controller('LoginCtrl', { $scope: $scope });
}));
```

Similarly, if your real controller has injections that you will be using for testing, you'll need to add them in. So for example (and this is only an example):

```
ctrl = $controller('LoginCtrl',
  {
    $scope: $scope,
    SomeService: SomeService,
    moment: moment,
    dateFormat: dateFormat
  });
```

Comment: I have tried `beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $scope, $route, LoginService) { ctrl = $controller('LoginCtrl', { $scope: $scope, $route: $route, LoginService: LoginService }); }));` to match the controller but now I get this error: **Error: [$injector:unpr] htt p://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/unpr?p0=%24scopeProvider%20%3C-%20%24scope**

Comment: @Si-N Still sounds like a familiar problem to me. I also have tried the above solution, but that is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer here which worked: [Angular Unit Test Unknown provider: $scopeProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27810179/angular-unit-test-unknown-provider-scopeprovider)

```
beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope, $route, LoginService)
{
    scope = $rootScope.$new();

    ctrl = $controller('LoginCtrl', { 
        $scope: scope
    });
}));
```

In my case I didn't actually need $scope injected into my controller, so I removed it an the original code now works:

```
beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope, $route, LoginService)
{
        ctrl = $controller('LoginCtrl');
}));
```

I need to read up on how mocks and injection works!